# Where to find microcontroller ADC sampling rate comparison?

Tags: microcontroller, adc, sampling

I need a microcontroller with an ADC sampling rate around 100Ksps at minimally 10bits, but finding any comparisons of different microcontrollers regarding sampling rates has proven to be quite difficult. The best source I have found is [this white paper](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc7926.pdf), where at page 12 there is a table of 5 uCs and their ADC sample rates... Not a very good source though.

If anyone could help me find an uC with higher sample rate, which could be ideally programmed without a special programming tool (like through an LPT port with avrdude, liko most of the AVR uCs or with an Arduino or with an USB to RS232 converter...), I would be most grateful.

Or please point me to some comparison tables, if there are any, and I can look for some uC that suits me.

Comment: Parametric search on any of the manufacturers websites?

Comment: You say both 100Ksps, which is possible with a lot (most?) of the modern microcontrollers, and later you say 'with a higher sampling rate'? Manufacturers will provide parametric search and select within his own products only :) What other features do you need? My personal pet uC, the LPC1114, can do ~ 400Ksps. Software downbloading via a serial link.

Comment: Damn I have been looking for something like a parametric search on the atmel.com site, but failed to find it... It's probably just too late already.

Comment: Higher sampling rate was supposed to be higher than ATMega328 with 10bit resolution has, which is about 30KHz I think... forgot to mention. Well I found the parametric search already now, that I know it was there. Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you maybe looking for something like the following?
In no particular order:

- [the Texas Instruments MSP430 parametric search](http://www.ti.com/lsds/ti/microcontroller/16-bit_msp430/products.page)
- [the Microchip parametric search](http://www.microchip.com/maps/) and [another Microchip parametric search](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=2661)
- the FreeScale parametric search: go to http://www.freescale.com/ , click "products", then click "parametric search"
- [Cypress PSoC1 parametric search](http://www.cypress.com/?id=1573) and [Cypress PSoC4 parametric search](http://www.cypress.com/?id=4749)
- [the Atmel parametric search](http://www.atmel.com/products/selector_overview.aspx)

Alas, the following distributors don't include a "sampling rate" column in their microcontroller parametric search tool (only a "number of ADCs" column). But they do have one in their ADC parametric search tool:

- [Digikey ADC parametric search](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/integrated-circuits-ics/data-acquisition-adcs-dacs-special-purpose/)
- [Mouser ADC parametric search](http://www.mouser.com/Semiconductors/Integrated-Circuits-ICs/Data-Converter-ICs/Analog-to-Digital-Converters-ADC/_/N-6j74v/)
- [Newark/Farnell ADC parametric search](http://www.newark.com/analog-to-digital-converters-adc)

Comment: I don't know about the others, but the TI and Microchip parametric searches don't provide info that I can see regarding the RATE of A/D, just the number of ADC channels and how wide they are.

Comment: For reference, Atmel gives the recommended ADC clock rate range and ADC timing diagram, from which one can infer a sample rate (although they tend to list it in the Features subsection at the beginning of the ADC section in their datasheets regardless).